# Why does voice recording cause a crash in my application on an original iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have created a voice recording app. It works fine on an iPhone 3G but crashes on an original 2G iPhone.

The crash occurs in the following methods:

```
-(void)RecordbtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [Record removeFromSuperview];
    stop.alpha=1;
    T=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self :@selector(startTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    persistance_Obj->recordClicked=TRUE;
    [AudioViewController_Obj startRecording];
}

-(void)StopbtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    printf("\n stop pressed");
    persistance_Obj->recordClicked=FALSE;
    [T invalidate];
    T=nil;
    [AudioViewController_Obj stopRecording];
    MainMenu * obj_RV=[[MainMenu alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_RV animated:YES];
    [obj_RV release];
}
```

The crash occurs right when I click the stop button, calling the second method.  What could be the cause of this crash?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, just get clear? The iPhone 1G you are talking about is actually the first released one and the iPhone 2G you are talking about is actually the iPhone 3G?

Maybe you could show us some code on where the app crashes?

Comment: 1G is first generation iphone i.e. first released one. 
iTs working fine in 2G and 3G iphones.
when i start recording it simply crashes and shows msg EXE_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I cant put code here I just know that when i click on button record its crashes. Here I am calling start recording function

Comment: Without code its gonna be really hard for us to help you with the problem. You dont need to put ALL the code of your project here, just the method you call when pressing the button.